# Entity framework não cria arquivo mdf

Tags: c#, entity-framework

No meu projeto ASP.net MVC5 ele cria o banco padrão pelo Visual Studio 2013.

Eu fui na pasta App_Data e deletei o arquivo mdf do banco, assim como o de log.

Eu estou querendo que ele crie novamente esse arquivo.

No meu arquivo de configuração, tenho o seguinte código.

```
   public class UserDBContext: DbContext 
    {

        public UserDBContext(): base("ConnectionString") 
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<UserDBContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<UserDBContext>());

        }
        public DbSet<Cliente> Clientes{ get; set; }
        public DbSet<Topico> Topicos{ get; set; }
    }
```

Ele passa, e não da nenhum erro, entretanto não cria o arquivo do banco de dados.

Comment: Você tem algum código que usa a classe de contexto, acessando os `DbSet`s? O EF usa uma estratégia de *lazy evaluation* que só executa o código quando é preciso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para recriar o MDF, botão direito no projeto > Adicionar > Novo Item, e escolha a opção **Banco de Dados Baseado em Serviço** ou então **Service-Based Database**:

[image: Banco de Dados Baseado em Serviço]

*Migrations* devem funcionar normalmente. Basta executar que as tabelas são recriadas dentro do seu arquivo. Não esqueça de atualizar sua `Connection String`.